# How to get selected value from <html:select>

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-select, struts-1

```
<html:select property="branchCombo" value="" name="selectBranchId">
    <c:forEach var="record" items="${branchList}">
        <option value="${record.id}">
            ${record.code} - ${record.name}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</html:select>
```

How can I get `id` from selected value from `<html:select>`?

Comment: where are your input tags ?

Comment: ID of record ? right ?

Comment: specify any id for your select tag and the use this script

var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)